# how do I put a request with double quotes, spaces and parenthesis inside a variable ? javascript

Tags: javascript, request, sapui5

I have something like this:

```
{
   "urn.getxxxx": {
       "urn.xxxx": "cxxxxx-44e9-xxxx-a91b-0000xxxx\\xxxxx\\3239750\\EO\\0\\",
       "urn.xxxx": "xxxxx",
       "urn.xxxxx": "x",
       "urn.xxxx": "2016-07-08T13:03:41+02:00"
   }
}
```

and i want to store it in a variable/object like `var request = "{...{..}..}";`
how do I do it?
I have errors becouse of the {} and the doublequotes.

```
I'm a novice sorry for my poor explanation. :)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var myObj = {
       "urn.getxxxx": {
           "urn.xxxx": "cxxxxx-44e9-xxxx-a91b-0000xxxx\\xxxxx\\3239750\\EO\\0\\",
           "urn.xxxx": "xxxxx",
           "urn.xxxxx": "x",
           "urn.xxxx": "2016-07-08T13:03:41+02:00"
       }
    };

var request = JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

[Stringify JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. It is better to mark is as duplicate instead of answering.